# How to get full arn when writing secret based IAM policy in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to create a permission set in cdk that grants `GetSecretValue` access to a specific secret. I get that secret by its name, using `Secret.fromSecretNameV2`. I know that when I get it by name, the full arn is not available, and so appending '-??????' to the resource arn when creating the policy works.

However, is there a prettier solution? This looks hacky.

The following is my current solution, which works, but doesn't feel ideal.

```
import { PolicyDocument, PolicyStatement } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
import { CfnPermissionSet } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sso';
import { Secret } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-secretsmanager';

      const databaseSecretName = `database-host`;
      const databaseSecret = Secret.fromSecretNameV2(
        this,
        'databaseSecret',
        databaseSecretName
      );

      const policy = new PolicyDocument({
        statements: [
          new PolicyStatement({
            actions: ['secretsmanager:GetSecretValue'],
            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
            resources: [databaseSecret.secretArn + '-??????'],
            sid: 'AllowDatabaseSecretReading',
          }),
        ],
      });

      new CfnPermissionSet(this, `PermissionSet`, {
        description: `blabla`,
        inlinePolicy: policy,
        instanceArn: prodIamIdentityCenterArn,
        managedPolicies: ['arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess'],
        name: this.name,
      });
```

Any tips are appreciated! Thanks!

I tried accessing `databaseSecret.secretFullArn`, but it's undefined. This is in line with what the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html#secretfullarn) says about secrets fetched by name.

Comment: There's `Secret.fromSecretCompleteArn`.

Comment: But I would need to know the full arn in the first place to fetch it this way, no? My problem is that I don't know the arn.

Comment: If you don't know the full ARN, you will have to use the partial ARN with the `-??????` suffix as you're doing.